# Text editor for exporting syntax-highlighted code in html format

Tags: linux, html, text-editors, syntax-highlighting

Long time along I used to export syntax-highlighted code from a certain text editor on the linux platform.
The idea is that it maps all the syntax-highlighting, like color, boldness, italics, indent, etc, to 
html tags, and you can post it anywhere as long as the site supports html, or you can convert from html to markdown or whatever, which should be easy enough.

The problem is I have forgotten the name of the editor. Anyone remembers?

Comment: I think this question belongs to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe these Linux editors support such HTML feature: **Geany**, **Kate**.